# Run php script in nodejs server

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Using a simple express server, I am hosting an html file that contains a form and input tag, allowing a user to upload images. Main.js (linked to index.html) processes and sends said file to upload.php which would move the image to an uploads directory. When the fetch api calls for upload.php `POST https://localhost/upload.php 404 (Not Found)` is thrown. Directly accessing `https://localhost/upload.php` downloads upload.php to my downloads directory.

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const ip = require("ip");

var app = express();

//current dir
const CWD = __dirname;
var clientIp;
var port = 443;

function getIp(req, res, next) {
  clientIp = req.ip;
  console.log("ip:" + clientIp);
  next();
}

app.use(getIp);
app.use(express.static(CWD + "/public/"), function (req, res, next) {
  next();
});

app.get("/"),
  function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(CWD + "index.html"));
  };

//https certificate and key
var sslServer = https.createServer(
  {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(CWD, "certificate", "key.pem")),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(CWD, "certificate", "certificate.pem")),
  },
  app
);

//determines which port app should listen on
sslServer.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("listening on" + port);
  console.log("CTRL + C to exit server");
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Skae FS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form" id="imgForm">
        <input type="file" id="inputImg"></input>
        <button type="submit">Upload Image</button>
    </form>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
const imgForm = document.getElementById("imgForm");
const inputImg = document.getElementById("inputImg");

imgForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const endpoint = "upload.php";
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("inputImg", inputImg.files[0]);

  //fetch request to upload.php
  fetch(endpoint, {
    method: "post",
    body: formData,
  }).catch(console.error);
});
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
//moves uploaded file to uploads dir
$targetPath = "uploads/" . basename($_FILES["inputImg"]["names"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["inputImg"]["tmp_name"], $targetPath);
```

Index.html, main.js and upload.php are all in the same "/public" directory and as evident by `https://localhost/upload.php` downloading upload.php are able to be accessed. My goal is for the upload.php to run and succesfully move inputImg.files[0] into the /uploads directory. If somebody recognizes what I am doing wrong I would appreciate a gesture in the right direction.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can’t run two server side languages on the same server+port combination. However, you can run a general purpose server, such as Nginx and others, and have it _invoke_ server side variants based on routes. The alternative is to just have PHP hosted on a different combination by a PHP-aware server, or just invoke PHP through the command line which is probably easier.

Comment: Why don't you just handle the upload using express? It seems a bit pointless to drag PHP into it as well.

Comment: @ADyson Could you elaborate on how I could do this? Tutorials online stuck to php when processing file uploads so I assumed that was the best way to go about it.